# Plotly: how to make an unbounded vertical line in a subplot?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-python

The goal is to get vertical infinite lines in every subplot, at x=1.
In this example, I'll just try a single plotly shape of type="line" in the first row, first column

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2,
    cols=2,
    subplot_titles=list(map(str, range(4))),
    shared_xaxes=True,
    shared_yaxes=False,
)

time = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 1000)

for i in range(4):
    data = np.sin((i+1) * time)
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(y=data,x=time, name=str(i)),
        row=1 if i in [0, 1] else 2,
        col=1 if i in [0, 2] else 2,
    )

fig.add_shape(
    go.layout.Shape(
        type="line",
        yref="paper",
        xref="x",
        x0=1,
        y0=0,
        x1=1,
        y1=1,
        line=dict(color="RoyalBlue", width=3),
    ),row=1,col=1)

fig.write_image("1.png",width=800, height=600, scale=1)
```

[image: Plot1]

So it looks like adding a shape with row and column overrides the yref and xref properties, returning a segment of a line instead of an infinite line.
Forcing yref to be "paper" before printing...

```py
for shape in fig.layout.shapes:
    shape["yref"]="paper"
```

...I get this:
[image: Plot2]

This is arguably worse, a line that's relative to the whole figure instead of the subplot y axis. Has anyone stumbled with this problem before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this your desired plot?

[image]

If that's the case then you'll have to inset a shape to each subplot defined by the positions `row=i,col=j`. The following snippet will do that for you. If you change the total numbers of subplots You'll just need to have som oversight of how your grid will look with regards to the numbers of rows and columns.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2,
    cols=2,
    subplot_titles=list(map(str, range(4))),
    shared_xaxes=True,
    shared_yaxes=False,
)

time = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 1000)

for i in range(4):
    data = np.sin((i+1) * time)
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(y=data,x=time, name=str(i)),
        row=1 if i in [0, 1] else 2,
        col=1 if i in [0, 2] else 2,
    )

colors = ['blue', 'firebrick', 'green', 'purple']
rows = 2
cols = 2

# add traces
counter=0 # for colors
for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(1,3):
        fig.add_shape(go.layout.Shape(type="line",
                                        yref="paper",
                                        xref="x",
                                        x0=1,
                                        y0=-2,
                                        x1=1,
                                        y1=2,
                                        #line=dict(color="RoyalBlue", width=3),),
                                        line=dict(color=colors[counter], width=3),),
                      row=i,
                      col=j)
        counter = counter + 1

fig.show()
```

**Edit after comments:**

To my knowledge, you can't define an unbounded directly. But what you're trying to accomplish *will* work pretty good as long as you define axis limits well beyond the data you want to visualize. Because contrary to your comment, you *can* set the axis limits of each subplot like this:

```
# Set y ranges for each subplot
for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(1,3):
        fig.update_yaxes(range=[-4, 4], row=i, col=j)
```

And instead of predefined limits you can find the proper max and min values from your datasets.

**Plot 2:** Unzoomed

[image]

**Plot 3:** Zoomed out

[image]

I hope this is a bit more helpful!

Comment: Hi! This would be bounded vertical lines, if I were to scroll the plot, the lines would only start at y=-2 and end at y=2. The goal is to set them as unbounded.

Comment: Furthermore, the min and max y axis values shouldn't be affected by the vertical line. I can get them to do this in a plot, but not in a subplot

Comment: @HalogenII How did my suggestion work out for you after the last edit?

Comment: Thanks @vestland, it's a hack, but it does the job. I'll be sure to set large enough bounds. Thanks for everything

Comment: Hopefully my English is not to bad so that I misunderstood the question, but can't you get "unbounded vertical lines" by replacing the corresponding keys in your code with `yref="y domain", y0=0, y1=1`?

Answer (score 1):

`add_vline`/`add_hline` methods were added in 4.12.0 for vertical and horizontal lines. Similar for other shapes too. See https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/. An example from those docs:

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="petal_length", y="petal_width")
fig.add_hline(y=0.9)
fig.add_vrect(x0=0.9, x1=2)
fig.show()
```