# Plotly: ticklabels problem in subplots with two rows

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

This is my plotly dash code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AmirForooghi/stocks_csv/master/stocks_sample.csv')

df_1 = data.loc[data.sym == 'f']
df_2 = data.loc[data.sym == 'i']
df_3 = data.loc[data.sym == 'c']

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=3, row_heights=[0.8, 0.2], vertical_spacing=0,
                    horizontal_spacing=0.05, shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=False)

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(open=df_1['open'], high=df_1['high'], low=df_1['low'],
                             close=df_1['close'],
                             increasing_line_color='#0384fc', decreasing_line_color='#e8482c'
                             ), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=list(range(40)), y=df_1['pct'], line_color='#fae823', hovertemplate=[]),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(open=df_2['open'], high=df_2['high'], low=df_2['low'],
                             close=df_2['close'],
                             increasing_line_color='#0384fc', decreasing_line_color='#e8482c'
                             ), row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=list(range(40)), y=df_2['pct'], line_color='#fae823', hovertemplate=[]),
              row=2, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(open=df_3['open'], high=df_3['high'], low=df_3['low'],
                             close=df_3['close'],
                             increasing_line_color='#0384fc', decreasing_line_color='#e8482c'
                             ), row=1, col=3)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=list(range(40)), y=df_3['pct'], line_color='#fae823', hovertemplate=[]),
              row=2, col=3)

fig.update_layout({'plot_bgcolor': "#21201f", 'paper_bgcolor': "#21201f", 'legend_orientation': "h"},
                  legend=dict(y=1, x=0),
                  font=dict(color='#dedddc'), dragmode='pan', hovermode='x unified', showlegend=False,
                  margin=dict(b=20, t=0, l=0, r=40))

fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, rangeslider_visible=False, showticklabels=False, showline=True,
                 linecolor='#969799', showspikes=True, spikemode='across', spikesnap='data',
                 spikedash='dash', spikecolor='#ebeae8', spikethickness=0.5)

fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=True, showline=False)

fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='skip', xaxis='x1', col=1)
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='skip', xaxis='x2', col=2)
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='skip', xaxis='x3', col=3)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id='chart', config={'displayModeBar': False}),
])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, dev_tools_ui=False, dev_tools_props_check=False)
```

My problem with this figure is that the ticklabels for y axis are not correct.
[image]
 As you can see, for the second  and third columns, it is removed and for the first column it is overlapping.
I tried the approach of this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62000223/python-plotly-adding-a-horizontal-line-to-a-scatter-plot-that-has-multiple-subp/62004276?noredirect=1#comment109664964_62004276) but if I remove those `fig.update_traces` the spikes that are present will change(refer to update 1 below for more information). What I mean by spikes, is illustrated below:
[image]
As can be seen when the cursor is on the scatterplots, It draws a line across the whole column.

I want to keep these spikes completely in tact as the way they are now. How can I fix the ticklabels problem now?

**UPDATE 1:**

If I remove the three `fig.update_traces` at the end of the code, the spikes are present but they are not what I want. It is illustrated by these two screenshots. The first one is the spikes that are in my original code and and the second one is the spikes without `fig.update_traces`:
[image]
[image]

The main difference is that spikes in the figure above are across the whole column and are only present when the cursor is on the scatterplot. I NEED it this way. It is not for better looks! They should stay exactly like the above figure.

Comment: Is what you're really aiming for to get that cross on hover without that hoverinfo again? But this time for multiple subplots?

Comment: If that is the case, then "how to apply crosshairs for multiple candlestick figures" is the real question here. And the ticklabels are really just a side-effect of reaching that goal.

Comment: @vestland I have already "applied crosshair for multiple candlesticks". If you run my code, you can see that for all three columns crosshair is working fine. I think the real problem is fixing the ticklabels problem while maintaining the crosshair with the style that I want. Crosshair is not a problem anymore. We solved that issue together with 99% percent of your help :)

Comment: I see... Just had me confused there since your snippet only produces a vertical and not horizontal spikeline. I'll take another look.

Comment: @vestland I understand. I want this style for three column charts.

Answer (score 2):

*This is an answer in progress...*

I removed:

```
 fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='skip', xaxis='x1', col=1)
 fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='skip', xaxis='x2', col=2)
 fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='skip', xaxis='x3', col=3)
```

And I'm getting this *with* the spikes as you can see your gif:

[image]

What am I missing?