# Plotly: How to highlight certain periods in a pandas time series with rectangle shapes using a For Loop?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to highlight timeperiods in Plotly. I seems like the best way is to use Shapes, like [this](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#highlighting-time-series-regions-with-rectangle-shapes), but in the real world you do not want to add each shape manually like in the example url. I am thinking a for loop is the best solution, but open for other (less computational) suggestions.

my script look like this:

```
np.random.seed(12345)
rows = 20
x = pd.Series(np.random.randn(rows),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=rows)).cumsum()
df = pd.DataFrame({"index": x})

# add column showing what to shade
df["signal"] = df['index'] < 5

# plot index and highlight periods with Rectangle Shapes in Plotly
fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y="index")

for row in df.iterrows():
    if df['signal'] == False:
        ply_shapes['shape_' + str(i)]=go.layout.Shape(type="rect",
                                                            x0=df.dato[i-1],
                                                            y0=0,
                                                            x1=df.dato[i],
                                                            y1=2000,
                                                            opacity=0.5,
                                                            layer="below"
                                                        )

lst_shapes=list(ply_shapes.values())
fig.update_layout(shapes=lst_shapes)
fig.show()
```

But this returns:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: Perfect, thank you:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several reasons why your code snippet will not work.

**1.** `iterrows()` returns an iterator containing the index of each row and the data in each row as a seres. To use this, you would have to replace

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    if df['signal'] == False:
```

with (for example):

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1]['signal'] == True:
```

Your error is raised bacause your are assigning a *series* of `True, False` with `if df['signal'] == False:` instead of a single value like `if row[1]['signal'` will do.

But only fixing this will not help you. At least not within the confinements of your snippet, because:

**2.** `dato` does not exist in your sample dataframe.

[Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494074/plotly-how-to-set-a-fill-color-between-two-vertical-lines/63495999#63495999) have been asked and answered before. But since the solution will be similar for very different sounding questions, I've decided to make a custom solution for your use case as well.

---

The best approach will in either case depend heavily on *how* you identify and assign your highlighted periods within your time series. The following example will use random data and identify periods to highlight depending on a threshold. Just like in your question.

My suggestion will boil down to a function `highLights()` that will take a a plotly figure, a pandas series and a threshold as input, as well as a few other details (take a look at the docstring).

#### The `highLights()` function with some example input:

```
fig = highLights(fig = fig, variable = 'signal', level = 5, mode = 'above',
               fillcolor = 'rgba(200,0,200,0.2)', layer = 'below')
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import datetime

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# data sample
cols = ['signal']
nperiods = 200
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 12, size=(nperiods, len(cols))),
                  columns=cols)
datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),periods=nperiods).tolist()
df['dato'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['dato'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.iloc[0] = 0
df = df.cumsum().reset_index()

# plotly setup
fig = px.line(df, x='dato', y=df.columns[1:])
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0.1)')
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0.1)')


# function to set background color for a
# specified variable and a specified level
def highLights(fig, variable, level, mode, fillcolor, layer):
    """
    Set a specified color as background for given
    levels of a specified variable using a shape.
    
    Keyword arguments:
    ==================
    fig -- plotly figure
    variable -- column name in a pandas dataframe
    level -- int or float
    mode -- set threshold above or below
    fillcolor -- any color type that plotly can handle
    layer -- position of shape in plotly fiugre, like "below"
    
    """
    
    if mode == 'above':
        m = df[variable].gt(level)
    
    if mode == 'below':
        m = df[variable].lt(level)
        
    df1 = df[m].groupby((~m).cumsum())['dato'].agg(['first','last'])

    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        #print(row['first'], row['last'])
        fig.add_shape(type="rect",
                        xref="x",
                        yref="paper",
                        x0=row['first'],
                        y0=0,
                        x1=row['last'],
                        y1=1,
                        line=dict(color="rgba(0,0,0,0)",width=3,),
                        fillcolor=fillcolor,
                        layer=layer) 
    return(fig)

fig = highLights(fig = fig, variable = 'signal', level = 5, mode = 'above',
               fillcolor = 'rgba(200,0,200,0.2)', layer = 'below')

fig.update_layout(template = 'plotly_dark')

fig.show()
```

Comment: please check out my question avilable on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72824450/how-do-i-highlight-or-draw-a-bounding-box-around-a-portion-of-certain-period and if possible please answer it. Thanks