# Is there a way to have add_vline vertical line extend indefinetely on the y axis?

Tags: python, plotly

As of plotly version 4.12, you can add Horizontal and Vertical Lines and Rectangles. I have installed plotly 4.12. I am using the following snippet:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="petal_length", y="petal_width")
fig.add_vline(x=2.5, line_width=3, line_dash="dash", line_color="green")
fig.add_hrect(y0=0.9, y1=2.6, line_width=0, fillcolor="red", opacity=0.2)
fig.show()
```

... which produces this figure:

[image]

Why does the vline does not extend indefinetely on the y axis?

Same problem is described here [github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2979](http://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2979) but no solution is provided. I can find descriptions of a workaround here: [Plotly: how to make an unbounded vertical line in a subplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59214406/plotly-how-to-make-an-unbounded-vertical-line-in-a-subplot) but the workaround is quite verbose and not so neat.

I would really like to use the add_vline functionality and I am a bit puzzled as [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html?highlight=add_vline#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.add_vline) clearly says "Add a vertical line to a plot or subplot that extends **infinitely** in the y-dimension." and all examples [here](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/) extends beyond 1 too: Therefore it looks to me like the intended behavior should be to have the line extends beyond 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add_vline function uses recently-added features in the underlying rendering engine, Plotly.js, meaning you need a recent version of Plotly.js wherever you are using Plotly.py. In practice this means installing the latest jupyterlab-plotly extension in JupyterLab, the latest dash/dash_core_components in Dash, or waiting until VSCode and/or Streamlit update their onboard copies of Plotly.js, if you’re seeing this problem in those environments.

More information can be found here: [Troubleshooting | Python | Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/troubleshooting/)